# how to show autocomplete template in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I read jasmine tutorial for controller testing  form here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shqptAMZ_NM

In this tutorial he used **nscontrollerspec** after that code is generated .could you please tell me the shortcut to generate the code ? as shown in video

**nscontrollerspec**

This video used webstrom is there any shortcut key to generate this template ? And developer also comment below that but no one give response of that comment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to Settings-> live templates then add a new live template called nscontrollerspec then in the template text you paste:

```
describe("$CONTROLLER$",function(){
    var $rootScope,
        $scope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('');

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $injector.get('$controller')("$CONTROLLER$",{$scope:$scope});
        });
    });
});
```